# How to draw a blurry circle on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, blur

I'm able to draw a simple circle on HTML5 canvas, but I'd like to add some blur around it.

What I found was [this website](http://flashcanvas.net/examples/uupaa-js-spinoff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/uuCanvas.js/demo/9_1_canvas_text_shadow_direction.html) which explains the `shadowBlur` property which can come in handy here.

However, I cannot manage to make the circle itself blurry. What the `shadowBlur` property basically does is painting some blur effect after the regular circle has been drawn. What I've tried so far I've put [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Kqy/1/).

As can be seen, it's a solid filled circle with some blur effect around it - the two parts do not blend into each other at all. What I actually would like to achieve is that the circle itself is fully blurred like this:

[image: blurred circle]

Is there any way to draw a blurred circle like this, i.e. that the circle itself also has a blur effect?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest against blur algorithms unless you are blurring some already-existing drawing that is complex.

For your case, just draw a rect with a radial gradient.

```
  var radgrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(60,60,0,60,60,60);
  radgrad.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,0,0,1)');
  radgrad.addColorStop(0.8, 'rgba(228,0,0,.9)');
  radgrad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(228,0,0,0)');

  // draw shape
  ctx.fillStyle = radgrad;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/r8Kqy/48/

Comment: +1 for using RGBA to get proper transparency in the blur region. Nice work.

Comment: But remember, this is not a real (gaussian) blur! This blur is made by  a "cone" with straight edge, real (gaussian) blur will look much softer. You can approximate it by adding more colorStops.

Comment: This is perfectly fine. But in my case, I need to work with imageData directly instead of context. Any way to add blur circle by modifying imageData directly ??

Answer (score 6):

You may find the [context.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) property useful

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.filter = "blur(16px)";

context.fillStyle = "#f00";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
context.fill();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas width=200 height=200 id='canvas'></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

*Note as of April 2017, IE, Opera and Safari don't support this*

Comment: still unsupported on safari as of july 2020

Comment: any alternate for ctx.filter method for iOS safari/chrome ?

Answer (score 4):

You probably can obtain the bitmap pixel array and apply some blurring algorithm on top of it. For example: http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html

Comment: Very interesting. However, as I'm using it a renderer (20fps) I guess it will become a little overcomplicated and slow... But I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: @pimvdb Blur it once to an offscreen canvas and then blit the result to your canvas using `drawImage()`.

Comment: Here's a better, very fast blur written for HTML5 Canvas: [StackBlur](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a blurred circle with the following function:

```
function drawblurrycircle(context, x, y, radius, blur)
{
     context.shadowBlur = blur;
     context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
     context.shadowOffsetY = 0;

     context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
     context.shadowColor="#FF0000"; //set the shadow colour to that of the fill

     context.beginPath();
     context.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
     context.fill();
     context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I already posted that I tried `shadowBlur`, and that the problem is that the shadow does not blend into the cicle. Your solution suffers from that very same issue, unfortunately. http://jsfiddle.net/r8Kqy/410/

Comment: Sorry! I did not read your post thoroughly. To make it look better, you could use a `for` loop to blur it multiple times

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested in seeing this effect done with EaselJS, this might help [JSFiddle EaselJS blur](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastian_derossi/Bw2w8/1/)

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("test");
var s = new createjs.Shape();
var g = s.graphics;
g.f("#FF0000").dc(0, 0, 75);
s.x = 100;
s.y = 100;
s.filters = [new createjs.BoxBlurFilter(5, 5, 3)];
stage.addChild(s);
s.cache(-100, -100, 200, 200);
s.alpha = 0.5;
stage.update();
```

Comment: Maybe it's because it's 6 years later, but the above JSFiddle doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @GrahamLea Yikes! you're correct, have a looks at this http://jsfiddle.net/s0c9wndh/
Seems like BoxBlurFilter is no longer used in the latest version, use BlurFilter instead
[code]
var stage = new createjs.Stage("test");
var s = new createjs.Shape();
var g = s.graphics;
g.f("#FF0000").dc(0, 0, 75);
s.x = 100;
s.y = 100;
s.filters = [new createjs.BlurFilter(5, 5, 3)];
stage.addChild(s);
s.cache(-100, -100, 200, 200);
s.alpha = 0.5;
stage.update();
[/code]