# Cut out an area of image within an Image Canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've two images, first is large image which is placed first and then another image is placed on it. Now I want to cut out area of second image over the first.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var first_img = new Image(),
      second_img = new Image();



   first_img.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
   second_img.src = 'http://tux.crystalxp.net/png/mimipunk-tux-cartoon-1820.png';

      var draw = function(){


          second_img.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(second_img, 50, 50);
          };

          first_img.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(first_img, 50, 50);
          };


      };

      draw();
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yRgTd/1/)

**edit**
second image is png and have irregular shape, I want the first image having transparency of area of the first image

Comment: I think this is what u are looking for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379818/html5-canvas-image-masking-overlapping I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The drawImage function provides parameter for that

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage%28%29)

Comment: the second image is png, the drawImage func don't take any parameter like that. I don't think it will work. can u pls pointout more in depth