# Kineticjs Complex Image Clipping

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs, clip

I tried to emulate this [other's Stackoverflow canvas clipping function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379818/html5-canvas-image-masking-overlapping)  in KineticJS with additional feature of draggable image, but I can't get it done.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dekaa/6L1wxt1g/

```
shape = new Kinetic.Shape({
    sceneFunc:function(ctx){
        ctx.drawImage(clipping_mask,0,0);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
        ctx.drawImage(main_image,0,0);
    },
    draggable:true
});
```

Tried to use sceneFunc function, when I use it the draggable feature is not working. So the question is can it be done in KineticJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx` argument is not native context.

```
    ctx.drawImage(clipping_mask,0,0);
    ctx.setAttr('globalCompositeOperation',"source-in");
    ctx.drawImage(main_image,0,0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6L1wxt1g/1/

Comment: Ah, Thanks a lot, I forgot about this. The globalCompositeOperation works now, but the draggable still not working.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's pretty much make sense now.