# transformation of canvas image edges

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an issue, I have a draggable canvas image in my background image,
thats all good:

```
// first clear the canvas
main_ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
// draw the background image
main_ctx.drawImage(bg_canvas, panoramaX,panoramaY, 600, 200);
// draw the img without the transforms applied :-(
main_ctx.drawImage(img_canvas, imageX, imageY);
```

But now I would love to transform edges of my image.
This should be the result of transformation:
[image: <a href="http://oi63.tinypic.com/29maskz.jpg">Here</a>]

Is it possible to transform image like this?
Thank for your time and help in advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "transform" -- your image doesn't make it clear.

Comment: I mean like when I place original image its like rectangle, but my image should have rounded bottom edge and image should be a little widespread.

Comment: I see now. **In its native 2d mode, html canvas cannot do what you want**. Native canvas will only stretch/squish rectangular images into parallelograms -- not something like your rounded trapezoid. You might look at 3d canvas mode (webGL).

Comment: Ok so do you think that webGL is the only way to solve my problem? Hope it's not such hard to learn this technology.

Comment: WebGL has a large learning curve. If you just want to warp a few images you might do it in Photoshop.

Comment: @markE I cannot use Photoshop because I never now how the image will look like. So far I found that I can change shapes of triangles etc. but is it possible to change shape of an image in WebGL?

Comment: This looks like some kind of mask to me, maybe you can mask an area of your canvas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379818/canvas-image-masking-overlapping

Comment: @Neil No, thats not what I'm looking for, i need to keep all content of my image. I need to distort original image into my shape. Thank you for reply!

Comment: @PetrBečka - But your example is showing a mask of an area, are you sure this is what the distorted image would look like?