# How to get image mask in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Can you help me please how to get a mask image with a transparent background like this using Canvas?

[image: original image]

[image: mask]

I tried to use `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor'` and adding 2 images but that's wasn't help me...

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379818/canvas-image-masking-overlapping?

Comment: Fill with a `.fillStyle = 'red`, `.fillRect( 0,0,w,h )`, then `globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in'` and you should get the cutout?